# Show which elements of a column cannot be converted to numeric in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

**The problem:**

I have a tibble column that I wish to convert to a numeric column. Most of the cells can be converted easily (i.e. "1" becomes 1, "NA" becomes NA). Some however cannot be converted easily (e.g. "1-4"), in these cases I am understandably given a "NAs introduced by coercion" error.

Is there a simple way or function (preferably in tidyverse style/syntax) that can show the rows that which were not easily converted to numeric.

**Reproducible example:**

```
tibble::tibble(x = 1:10, 
               y = c("11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18-21", "22", "23")) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(y = as.numeric(y))
```

**The output I looking for  in this case is:**

|  | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 8 | "18-21" |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need a `filter` on the `NA` elements after converting to `numeric` as non-numeric elements are converted to `NA` which is picked up by `is.na` as a logical vector and this can be used in `filter` to get those rows

```
library(dplyr)
tibble::tibble(x = 1:10, 
                y = c("11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18-21", "22", "23")) %>% 
     mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
     filter(is.na(as.numeric(y)))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 1 x 3
      x y        rn
  <int> <chr> <int>
1     8 18-21     8
```

---

With `as.numeric`, there is a friendly warning that says the function returns NA for some elements.  If we want to avoid that, use a regex pattern to filter those rows i.e. `\\D` - will look for any non-digits in the dataset

```
library(stringr)
tibble::tibble(x = 1:10, 
                y = c("11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18-21", "22", "23")) %>% 
     mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
     filter(str_detect(y, '\\D'))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 1 x 3
      x y        rn
  <int> <chr> <int>
1     8 18-21     8
```

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you for your help. Personally I prefer the second approach without warnings.

Comment: @FreddieJ.Heather you could wrap with `suppressWarnings` to avoid printing the warning messages as well.  But, I would not use it warnings give some important information

Comment: Side note for future readers: I found that replacing `\\D`  with `[^.0-9]+` would incorporate decimal numeric values as well.

Comment: @FreddieJ.Heather I was thinking about updating it, but thought that you had only those patterns as showe din the example